# Merge some cells depending on certain cell value

Tags: excel, vba

So, I would like to merge some cells and I would like to do it like this:

[image]

In the picture above I've presented the kind of merge that I would like to have. So, if I enter some text in cell `B6` I'd like to cell range `C6:F9` and `G6:K9` to be merged. If `B10` than `C10:F13` and `G10:K13`. and so on ...

Also, text in these merged cells should be wrapped.

When I enter code I'll have automatically generated text in this merged cells. That text will be large and it needs to be wrapped.

I've tried a lot of things with formulas, looked for something that could help me. I know that with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code I could do this but I'm not into VBA programming/code/...!

If there is someone that could help me, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Macro-recorder for all the manual steps you describe will produce relevant code. Also you'll need Worksheet Change event to track changes in cells and update others automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- right-click your sheet tab
- `View Code`
- copy and paste in the code below

This code will run the merge only for every 4th cell changed in column B, starting from `B2`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
For Each rng2 In rng1
'If rng2.Row > 1 Then
If (rng2.Row - 2) Mod 4 = 0 Then
With rng2.Offset(0, 1).Resize(4, 4).Cells
.MergeCells = True
.WrapText = True
End With
End If
'End If
Next
With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, I've asked this new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916003/excel-formula-in-vba-code so if you could look at it. It kind of ties to this question. Once again, than you for everything!!!