# Excel formula in VBA code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So, in Sheet1 I have base of some names and it looks like this:

[image]

In Sheet2 I'm working with these names from Sheet1. I'm doing that in a way that I'm entering Code value in column A and in column B I get the Name, in column C I get the Last Name. That looks like this:

[image]

I've done this with formulas, entering it in the formula bar. For column A(or Name) I've used this formula: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!A:C;2;FALSE);"")` and for column B(or Last Name) I've used this one: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!A:C;3;FALSE);"")`. I've dragged these formulas to row 20 and it works great.

Now, what I'd like to do is to put these formulas into Excel VBA code and them to work for noted range. I've just started to use VBA and I don't know how to do it in it, tried something but doesn't work, ..., I've done this so far. I'm new to this Excel/Macro/VBA thing so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Really, don't use Excel for that task but a relational database. It's excactly what those are designed for. If it has to be Microsoft Office, then you can use Access.

Comment: In such situations, Excel can be used easily as a database replacement. It much more versatile esp. when it comes to calculations - and the different lookup functions help you to get some DB functionality.

Comment: what exactly do you want the macro to do? if you only want to place a formula in a range, you can try something like `Range("B2:B20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:C,2,FALSE);"""")"`

Comment: I'm not using Excel in purpose of some kind database rather as quick presentations of something. So, my intention is not to make DB but to do something else. Also, I agree with Peter and he is 100% right I'm using this just because of that DB functionality.

Comment: Show the "Excel VBA" code (give context) and explain *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: well, first of all you can easily delete formulas from cell and than you don't have what you wanted. with macros I think that it's another story.

Comment: I've had users save .xlsm workbooks to .xls thus deleting all macros from the workbook. By chance we had a few spares in archives.

Comment: Please share what you tried in VBA. Also you can record a macro, this being record what you do on screen then go to the code and tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will work if you type in your `Code` values in `sheet2` and highlight them, and run this macro:

```
Selection.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!C[-1]:C,2,FALSE),"""")"
Selection.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Sheet1!C[-2]:C,3,FALSE),"""")"
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value
Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value = Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value
```

**Edit:** If you are wanting to update values as you type use (thank you @PeterAlbert for added optimisation!):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'end if the user made a change to more than one cell at once?
    If Target.Count > 1 Then End

    'stop system activating worksheet_change event while changing the sheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'continue if column 1(A) was updated
    'and
    'dont continue if header or row 1 was changed
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <> 1 Then

        With Target.Offset(0, 1) 'alter the next cell, current column +1 (column B)

            'RC1 = current row and column 1(A) e.g. if A2 was edited, RC1 = $B2
            'C1:C2 = $A:$B
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,Sheet1!C1:C2,2,FALSE),"""")"
            .Value = .Value 'store value
        End With

        With Target.Offset(0, 2) 'alter the next cell, current column +2 (column C)

            'C1:C3 = $A:$C
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,Sheet1!C1:C3,3,FALSE),"""")"
            .Value = .Value 'store value
        End With

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True 'reset system events
End Sub
```

**Explinatioin of RC:**

The `FormulaR1C1` formula types are good to use when referencing a cell with respect to the current cell. There a few rules to remember:

- The `R` stands for Row and `C` is for Column and the integer after it, if any, defines the row or column;
- As a basis the `RC` formula references itself;
- Any number following the `R` or `C` wraped in `[]` is an offset to itself, e.g. if you are in cell `A1` and use `R[1]C[1]` you would be referencing cell `B2`;
- Also any number following the `R` and `C` is an exact, e.g. if you reference `R2C2` no matter the cell you are in would also point to `B2`; and

To complicate things if you were in cell `C5`, e.g. using `Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 =` and coded the follwing:

1. `"=RC[-1]"` references cell `B5`
2. `"=RC1"` references cell `A5`, more rightly `$A5`
3. `"=R[1]C[-2]"` references cell `A6`
4. `"=Sum(C[-1]:C5)"` is `=Sum(B:E)`, more rightly `=Sum(B:$E)`

Comment: Thank you for this! This code indeed does what I need but selection continues to go to the end of columns. I've put this into Worksheet_Change procedure and that happened. do you have any idea why? How to solve that?

Comment: @glh: Two improvement options: 1. Use the `WITH Selection` statement 2. Instead of `rng.Copy/rng.PasteSpecial`simply use `rng.Value = rng.Value`

Comment: @Sylca, this is because the method I've used changes the values and as such an endless loop will occur until the last column is reached.

Comment: Thank you @glh! I still do not fully understand VBA code as I should, so I'm interested now in what do I need to change in this last code update for this next example to work the same?! Let's say that I'm entering these code values in column B and I want result of these formulas in column C and D. I've tried to change few things but didn't work! Hope you understand my question and one again Thanks!!!

Comment: @Sylca, Change `Target.Column = 1` to `... = 2`. In this case I've just checked to see if column a was updated, changing to 2 will check for column b instead.

Comment: Or you should use `enableevents` property instead similar to @PeterAlbert's answer, but only if any value  being entered in sheet 2 is going to need the name and last name added as this will do it for all cell updates.

Comment: @glh I'm trying to understand this whole Excel/VBA story and this answer of yours to be able to apply it on my actual scenario. For better understanding what my real problem is and what I need, here are two images: http://www.imagetoo.com/?v=screenbxb.jpg and http://www.imagetoo.com/?v=screentnt.jpg 
You'll see that cells order in Sheet2 is not simple rather random and its hard for me to refer to certain cell in Sheet1. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: @glh I'm just starting to understand formulas (whole RC[-1], ... stuff) so some small explanation based on my actual scenario will be the best. You can send me answer on my profile e-mail. I'd be so grateful for your help!!! And again, thanks for everything.

Comment: @glh Once again, thank you on this clear and thorough answer!!! This helped my a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question and comments correctly, you want to ensure that columns B&C always show you the right values based on your formula, but also want to protect (and maybe even hide the formula) from the users.

I'd suggest you use sheet protection instead: all you need to do is to unlock the cells you want the users to edit, i.e. select column A and in the _ Format cells_ dialog uncheck "Locked" in the *Protection* tab. Similarly for columns B&C, check "Hidden". Now right click the sheet name and select *Protect Sheet*. Once this is done, the user can edit column A - but will not see the formula in B&C and cannot edit those cells.

If for some reasons you need to ensure this in VBA, use the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    With Target.Offset(, 2 - Target.Column).Resize(, 2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,Sheet1!C1:C3,COLUMN(RC),0),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You need to place this in the module of the worksheet.

Comment: I'd like to ensure this in VBA! Reasons are, e.g., that I don't know how to SUMPRODUCT cells that have formulas in it. Another one, if I drag formula down to next page that page will be active and I don't need that.

Comment: Also, in your answer you've took value from row B from Sheet1. How to take value from column C from Sheet1? I don't fully understand how you reference to certain column/row/cell. Again, thank you for your effort, you are from great help for me!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: You can apply SUMPRODUCT to cells with formulas the same way you apply it to values! Not sure I understand your issue with the dragging of the formula (the macro in the answer will not address this either.) regarding the formula: I combined both formulas into one - I replaced the `2` and the `3`respectively with `COLUMN(RC)`. This will return the column number of the cell, i.e. `2` in column B and `3`in column C.

Comment: @Sylca: Just saw your edit - thanks! If it solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Also, I'm writing you an e-mail considering this whole story. hope that is not a problem?